# Trouble when adding control dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have page which contains 'base' usercontrol. This usercontrol needs to load usercontrols dynamically. I've written one of these controls for test, it's called `ContentTemplate` and it's type is `ContentTemplateType`. 
In the Page_Load event of the 'base' usercontrol i've the next code: (ph - asp:PlaceHolder)

```
ph.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<!-- ko if: {0} -->", cond)));
ph.Controls.Add(new ContentTemplate());
ph.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<!-- /ko -->"));
```

But in the end on the page i have only `<!-- ko if: live == false -->` and `<!-- /ko -->` lines.
I've tried the next code too:

```
ph.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl(ContentTemplateType, null));
```

but with the same result.
What i've done wrong?

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve can you tell us more briefly what you want to achieve and whats not happening?

Comment: I want `ContentTemplate` usercontrol to be rendered between `<!-- ko -->` tags

Answer (score 1):

Please use this

```
Control ctrl = Page.LoadControl("UserControlPath");

ph.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

For more details visit [Template Control Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I do not want to use this overload, which depends on path. I've tried to use overload where first parameter is type of control, but it didn't work.